Cannot run high number of parallel RPC queries against Octez v19.1
I run a program that needs to constantly run a large number of parallel queries against a private archive Octez node. Ever since I upgraded my node to v19.1 for the latest protocol upgrade, the response time has gone down a lot and I cannot run more than a few queries at a time. I used --max-active-rpc-connections=10000 and even --max-active-rpc-connections=10000000 with octez-node but did not see any improvement.
Is there any way I can still run hundreds of queries in parallel against octez-node?

The problem is exactly with v19.1. When I downgrade to v19.0 everything works again. Maybe someone from the Nomadic team will acknowledge this issue and look at it.

I think the 19.2 update addresses this issue.
